# cron can't read PYTHONPATH environment variables?

Tags: python, environment-variables, cron, crontab

I have added to the PYTHONPATH on my server's .bash_profile file. However it appears that cron isn't reading from it because I am getting import errors. If I run the exact command cron calls on the command line it works, but if I send the error output of cron to a separate file, its failing on the imports.

how can I structure it so that cron is aware of my appended PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cron` doesn't read shell startup files. You need to explicitly set the environment you need in the `crontab` or in the script that is being run. You can place variable assignment statements directly in the `crontab`:

```
PYTHONPATH=/dir1:/dir2
```

Each directory you need will have to be listed, because you can't append to it since the previous value isn't available.

Answer (score 2):

Include at the begining of the script.

```
. [directorypath].bash_profile
```